# Disable Symfony2 session for several controllers?

Tags: php, events, session, symfony, assetic

Is it possible to disable the session-management only for several controllers in Symfony2? The reason is, the application uses the pdo-database as sessionsavehandler and assetic. The assetic controller calls causes a lot (>45) unessesary db-queries. What is a recommented way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. All CSS/JS is only called via controller in dev-mode. In prod-mode only precompiled files are included. No controller, no session.